# Elements not added to DOM by generator function

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been pulling my hair out trying to make this simple code work. It should render input fields in the given DOM, but it doesn't. Why not?

```
var elems = 10;

function generateElems() {

    for (var i = 0; i < elems; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    }

    //Clean up
    var obj = null;
    var elems = null;
}

generateElems();
```

Comment: `var elems = null;` is *not* cleanup, it's redundant code that is breaking your script. You don't need to "cleanup" variables this way.

Comment: We will need to see your HTML structure as well. Does your document have a DIV tag?

Comment: What is `obj`? Please show us your full script and a demo how you're using it (including HTML markup). With that "cleanup", you cannot call the function twice, but what you have currently posted should work.

Comment: elems will always be empty because of javascript scope rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pHkTg/3/)

You are dealing with JavaScript variable hoisting here. Remove this line `var elems = null;` and your code should work.

It is considered best practise in JavaScript to declare all variables at the top of the function body.

Read this article for more information on JavaScript [hoisting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/).

As we are discussing best practises, it's worth making a note that appending elements in loops is a bad idea for performance. You should use `createDocumentFragment` instead to append the elements to and then dump this to DOM. It saves expensive document reflows and makes significant difference in performance.

```
var elems = 10;

function generateElems() {

    var d=document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = 0; i < elems; i++) {
        d.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(d); 

    //Clean up
    //var obj = null;
    //var elems = null;  ----> Commented out this line, it was causing the problem.  
}

generateElems();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set elms to null.

```
var elems = 10;

function generateElems() {

    for (var i = 0; i < elems; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    }
}


generateElems();
```